# Scala: singleton in an utility function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, singleton

I have the following code:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.language.Metaphone;

    object MyUtility {

      def metaphoneKey(data: DataClass): String = {

        val metaphoner = new Metaphone
        val field1 = metaphoner.encode(data.getField1)
        val field2 = metaphoner.encode(data.getField2)
        field1 + "_" + field2
      }
    }
```

The above code works fine, but I am wondering if this is a good enough programming practice? Should I make the metaphoner a singleton/static in MyUtility? BTW, this utility will be called in a Spark job, i.e.

```
 val output = input.map { t => MyUtility.metaphoneKey(t)}
```

Please advice. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it, but before you should go to documentation and check if it's safe to use same `Metaphone` class instance from different threads.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Metaphone.html

> This class is `conditionally thread-safe`. The instance field maxCodeLen
>   is mutable setMaxCodeLen(int) but is not volatile, and accesses are
>   not synchronized. If an instance of the class is shared between
>   threads, the caller needs to ensure that suitable synchronization is
>   used to ensure safe publication of the value between threads, and must
>   not invoke setMaxCodeLen(int) after initial setup.

Check if it's applied for your case ...

Comment: It looks like it would be better to initialize `Metaphone` per partition.

Answer (score 1):

While you could use a singleton utility class to do this, I'd consider using a case class. You have to ask yourself the reason for using a global utility class  to accomplish this. The case class is thread-safe and can be used in matching.

Also, when considering class design, a strongly named class delivers stronger readability than a general purpose utility class.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.language.Metaphone;

case class MetaphoneKey(data: DataClass) {
  lazy val field: String = {
    val metaphoner = new Metaphone
    val field1 = metaphoner.encode(data.getField1)
    val field2 = metaphoner.encode(data.getField2)

    field1 + "_" + field2
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So how to use the case class the same as a Utility class in my map function:  val output = input.map { t => MetaphoneKey(t)}  ?

Comment: Close - just call `field` afterwards: `val output = input.map { t => MetaphoneKey(t).field }`

Comment: But for this application, a singleton probably would work equally as well. I tend to prefer small instance classes favoring a strong class name when considering the readability of my class design. Utility classes feel more like miscellaneous buckets and should be avoided if a well-named class will do.